# Spotfire script to filter multiple tables without relationships

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I was able to approximate the minimum functionality that I'd need with the code below. It's incredibly kludgy. I would really appreciate some feedback on the code to make it better. In particular, I would love to preserve the filter cascading. Thanks.

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters as filters
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import FilterTypeIdentifiers

aProp= Document.Properties["DistinctReasons"]

thePanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel

theFilter = thePanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("Reason")
theFilter2 = thePanel.TableGroups[1].GetFilter("Reason")

theFilter.FilterReference.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter
theFilter2.FilterReference.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter

thelistboxFilter = theFilter.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()
thelistboxFilter2 = theFilter2.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()

thelistboxFilter.IncludeAllValues = False
thelistboxFilter2.IncludeAllValues = False

thelistboxFilter.SetSelection(aProp)
thelistboxFilter2.SetSelection(aProp)
```

I have a dashboard featuring two tables with matching columns. I would like to be able to filter both tables without creating a standard relationship, as this creates artificial parity between the tables.

The code below may address this, but I don't know how to implement it. I found it [here](https://community.tibco.com/questions/filtering-two-tables-without-creating-relationship-it-possible#node-1102646). I have two specific questions:

How is the variable myColNames supposed to be populated? And how should I properly assign this to a doc property. This is what I have done:

I created a document property named DocPropMultiList: [Property Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1sSi.png) and assigned the script. To populate myColNames, I passed a string with a column name, and that appears to do something, but the script still fails 
'''
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in ExecuteForDebugging
      File "", line 83, in 
      File "", line 78, in Clear_or_Filter
    NameError: name 'DocPropMultiList' is not defined
'''

Full disclosure: I am at my fourth month of learning Python, which has helped, and I know next to nothing to IronPython implementation in Spotfire. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters as filters
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import FilterTypeIdentifiers
from System import String

def ChangeFilterstoListBox():
    #CHANGE ALL FILTERS TO LISTS BOX
    for aPage in Document.Pages:
       aFilterPanel = aPage.FilterPanel
       for aTableGroup in aFilterPanel.TableGroups:
          for aFilterHandle in aTableGroup.FilterHandles:            
             if aFilterHandle.FilterReference.Name == myColName:
                aFilterHandle.FilterReference.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter

def DocPropertyList():
    # Set Values As List from Document Property
    mySelection = list(Document.Properties[DocPropMultiList])   
    return mySelection

def GetCurrentDict():
    d = dict()
    for x in Document.Data.Tables:
        #Check Column Name vs List of Columns from Table
        if myColName in [str(item) for item in x.Columns] :         
            # get filter
            filter = Document.FilteringSchemes[0][x][x.Columns[myColName]]       
            # get current filter type
            filterType = filter.TypeId       
            # change to checkbox to easily access unique value
            filter.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.CheckBoxFilter         
            # Capture List of Items from CheckBoxFilter
            mycountry_list = [value for value in filter.As[filters.CheckBoxFilter]().Values]     
            # return to old filter type
            filter.TypeId = filterType
            #Append to Dict     
            for item in mycountry_list:
                 d.setdefault(x.Name, []).append(item)
    return d 

def GetMyUpdateDict():
    d = GetCurrentDict()
    mySelection =DocPropertyList()
    for i in d:
        #Combine With DocPoperty List 
        combined = list(set(mySelection) & set([x for x in d[i]]))
        #Update Dictonary With Matching Values Only  
        d.update({i:combined})
    return d

def RunFilters():
    MyDict = GetMyUpdateDict()
    myPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
    for item in myPanel.TableGroups:    
        #print(item.Name)
        if item.GetFilter(myColName):
            myString = ",".join(MyDict[item.Name] )
            myFilter = item.GetFilter(myColName)
            lbFilter = myFilter.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()
            lbFilter.IncludeAllValues=False
            strVals = myString
            if strVals!=String.Empty:
              print(myString, item.Name )
              lbFilter.SetSelection(strVals.split(','))
            else:
              print(myString, item.Name )
              lbFilter.IncludeAllValues=False

def ClearFilters():
    myPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
    for item in myPanel.TableGroups:
        if item.GetFilter(myColName):
            myFilter = item.GetFilter(myColName)
            lbFilter = myFilter.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()
            lbFilter.Reset()

def Clear_or_Filter():
    ChangeFilterstoListBox()
    if Document.Properties[DocPropMultiList] != None: 
        RunFilters()
    else:       
        ClearFilters()

Clear_or_Filter()
```

Comment: Typically, if you see an ironpython script like this with a variable that appears to never be defined, it's defined in "Script parameters" underneath where you'd edit this script in Spotfire. Double click myColName and then click "Add" so you can define it.

Answer (score 1):

DocPropMultiList property control should be multilist document property with the filtering values.

The MyColName variable should be added in the script parameters as a string (ex:'Column_Name') which is the name of the column you are filtering. Column name being the same for both tables.

I believe I wrote the original script quite long because when trying to set both filters some problems would occur when one value was present in one table but not the other.

Comment: Hi. I definitely visited your site while researching. I was able to implement the code. In the end, it was simpler than I thought it would be. I was also able to do a similar process for dates with simple python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a property control and using data limiting expressions? This would let you filter two visualizations without creating a relationship between them, with no need for a script.